# third party Payment gateways in app

Tags: google-play-store

I am developing an app and integrating third party payment gateway for in-app purchases. So, all purchases happen by payment gateway; Is there any problem if I dont use google's in-app purchases payment?

I tried to read on android [launch checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html) 
, but its not clear whether I still can by-pass or not use google's in-app feature.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53072/google-play-3rd-party-payment-allowed